# SqlCommand returns null even tho there is data in the database

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I am looking at my code for a few hours now and I seriously can't seem to be able to find what is wrong.

The actual problem is that whenever I run my query it seems to be returning a null type also I am sure there is data in the database.

Error given:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Value cannot be null.
```

I'll paste in some of my code that I use.

App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MarkProject.Properties.Settings.MoviesConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MoviesUML.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Database.cs (My own class to fetch data from the db, only showing the Select method and my connection string as that's what's giving troubles)

Connection String:

```
private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MarkProject.Properties.Settings.MoviesConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Select Method:

```
public DataTable Select(string query, Dictionary<string, object> values = null)
{
    using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection))
        {
            myConnection.Open();

            if(values != null)
            {
                foreach(var item in values)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + item.Key, item.Value);
                }
            }

            this._dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            this._dataAdapter.Fill(this._dataTable);

            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }

    return this._dataTable;
}
```

And the query that I am running that gives the error.

```
DataTable movieData = this._db.Select("SELECT Title, Year FROM Movie");
```

And here is proof that the table is actually populated.

[image: Proof of data in database]

Comment: I would ask on this one for sure if you have even stepped through the code..? put break points and see if the `_dataTable` has anything in it before closing the connection..

Comment: |DataDirectory| points to BIN\DEBUG when you run your session. The database in that folder has no records while the database shown by Server Explorer is probably located in your project folder. Do you have Copy To Output Directory set to never for your MDF file?

Comment: also looks like your problem is in this line `this._dataAdapter.Fill(this._dataTable);` I would use a DataSet to fill from your Select command

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yes, that line is giving me problems. Altho in other projects I used the exact same functionality and it worked perfectly fine. There seems to be an issue with the Db or the db connection. Yes my database is just in my project folder. And no, I have the Copy to Output Directory set to Copy always.

Comment: I can refactor your code it will depict how to use the Fill Mehtod with a DataAdapter

Comment: @DJKRAZE If that is the better way to do it then please submit me that answer. I'm here to improve.

Comment: I will submit a way that can save you some time also no need to close the connection since it's wrapped in a `using`

Comment: also how come you are using a parameterized query that passes in parameters.. `DataTable movieData = this._db.Select("SELECT Title, Year FROM Movie");` I can't see parameters at all, I see that the query is Selecting `Title, Year` from movies but where is the Where clause if that's the case why not select * from Movie..? can you also clear up what you want your query to look like..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE In this case I am not using parameters, but I will use it in other queries in my project. Trust me, my code seriously isn't the thing that's wrong. It might not be perfect. I just need to be able to connect to the proper db atm.

Comment: ok no problem.. also I updated the answer with the correct `dt` datatable to fill glad I could show you a shorter way as well of implementing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public DataTable Select(string query, Dictionary<string, object> values = null)
{
    using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection))
        {
            myConnection.Open();

            if(values != null)
            {
                foreach(var item in values)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + item.Key, item.Value);
                }
            }

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt = new DataTable("YourDataTable");
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(dt);            
        }
    }
    return dt
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I will use this in my project for sure. Altho my problem is still not fixed with it. I am hopefully able to work it out with @Steve as I think he knows what is up. Something must be going wrong with my db.

Comment: I think the problem is in the query personally I can't see where you are passing values in the code to the method..

Comment: Because I will use it in other queries, the dictionary is set to null as default. Which means that it isn't required in the method >.>

Comment: You actually solved my issue here, what I did wrong was I did not instanitiate the datatable property that I had set.......

Comment: I know ..I saw that right off the bat.. but I am glad I was able to give you a scaled down version of how to do this.. I also have methods created as well to do the same for `DataSets` glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

It is the reverse of a very common scenario. It is always a misunderstanding of the meaning of |DataDirectory| in a WinForms app. The [substitution string |DataDirectory|](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-) points at the BIN\DEBUG folder (or x86 variant) when you debug your app inside Visual Studio. So all the commands runs against a database located in that folder. Usually this creates problem with INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE operation but also the SELECT could be affected if the two databases contains different data.

To resolve it copy the MDF file from your project folder in your BIN\DEBUG folder, then create a second connection in your Server Explorer. This one points to the database file in the BIN\DEBUG folder and use it to check if your commands work.

Comment: I checked my BIN\DEBUG Folder, but the database is not even in there. How is it possible that it can create the connection without the database even being there? Why Didn't it already give the error when creating the db connection?

Comment: What is your target CPU? if x86 then check on BIN\x86\DEBUG.

Comment: Okay I am kinda confused, do you mean the BIN\DEBUG folder in the project itself? I am running 64 bits Windows 8.1 on this computer.

Comment: Did you try to manually copy your MDF in the BIN\DEBUG folder? The x86 subfolder exists only if you set yout Platform Target CPU as 32bit (or prefer 32 bit). Check your BUILD->Configuration Manager (or the project properties BUILD page )

Comment: Yes I mean the BIN\DEBUG subfolder of the project folder. This is the startup directory of your app (unless you have changed it in the project properties). And, no, when creating the SqlConnection instance no attempt to check the presence of the file is performed. You need to try to open the connection to receive the error

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your explaination but I have made one of the most stupid mistakes ever. The problem was that I wasnt instanitiating my datatable.... So thanks alot for your time, but this wasn't the actual problem!

Comment: No problem then, but be aware of the AddWithValue receiving objects insted of typed values. You are running for surprises here and some headaches

Comment: Alright, so do you mean that I should ALWAYS give the type with AddWithValue? Like string/int whatever.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and also  [How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)